# Probability of a subset to contain another subset

Tags: probability, combinations

In a peer to peer network, a file is broken in N chunks. In a particular moment every peer in the network has a random number of chunks and no peer has all the chunks. 
If peer A has 'na' chunks and peer B has 'nb' chunks what is the probability for peer A to have all the chunks of peer B.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the chunks held by peer A to be fixed.  Then there are $\binom{N}{n_b}$ sets of chunks that peer B might have, of which $\binom{n_a}{n_b}$ are subsets of the set of chunks that peer A has.  Assuming all subsets are equally likely, the probability is
$$ \left.\binom{n_a}{n_b}\right/\binom{N}{n_b} $$

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following. Let's consider each chunk X. As A has $n_A$ chunks, the probability of A having X is $\frac{n_A}{N}$. The probability of B having X is $\frac{n_B}{N}$.

Now, if peer A has all chunks of peer B, for each chunk X we may have the following options:

1. A has X and B has X with probability $\frac{n_An_B}{N^2}$
2. A has X and B hasn't X with probability $\frac{n_A(1-n_B)}{N^2}$
3. A hasn't X and B hasn't X with probability $\frac{(1-n_A)(1-n_B)}{N^2}$

So, the answer would be $\left(\frac{1 - n_B + n_An_B}{N^2}\right)^N$